# How to randomly pick key from dict and change value?

Tags: python

I want to randomly select an animal and if there is no value 0 then decrease the value by 1.
I want to repeat the action twice.
Try:

```py
animals = {
"pets": {"dog": 2, "cat": 1, "mouse": 0}}

a = random.choice(list(animals["pets"]))
```

but this only displays the name of the animal.
I would like to get a result like this:
dog 1, cat 0, mouse 0

How to do it?
Thank you and best regards.

Comment: try this: `random.choice(list(animals["pets"].items()))`

Comment: Do you want to pick a random pet, or do you want to print a list of pets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to choose a random animal and then decrease the value associated with that animal each time it is chosen. I will also assume you don't want these values to go below 0. This can be done as follows:

```
import random

animals = {
"pets": {"dog": 2, "cat": 1, "mouse": 0}}

# I wasn't sure what else to name this
def KillPet(animals):
    pets = animals["pets"]
    pet = random.choice(list(pets.keys()))
    if pets[pet] > 0:
        pets[pet] -= 1
        return True
        # A pet was successfully removed
    # A pet was not removed
    return False

numberOfPetsRemoved = 0

# Remove 2 pets
while numberOfPetsRemoved < 2:
    success = KillPet(animals)
    if success:
        numberOfPetsRemoved += 1

print(animals)
```